# How to create (or extend) a Python 3.x embeddable zip for windows

Tags: python, windows, zip

my goal is to create or re-bundle an embeddable zip, like the one on the python dl page https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/ "Windows x86-64 embeddable zip file".

But how do they create such zip? I couldn't find a script or any documentation on how to do it. I also tried to extend it by generating pyc files and copy them inside the zip, but this didn't work so far.

Also the generated pyc files *(created with python -m compileall)* are a bit different from the zip files. They don't have the full path inside as a comment for example.

Ideally I would install some packages via pip and then re-bundle them inside the zip.

Thank you in advance

EDIT:
I want to know how to create the python36.zip (which is inside the Windows x86-64 embeddable zip)

Comment: When you extract embeddable zip file, you will find that all the modules are actually inside another zip python3x.zip file.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do this, extract Python embeddable zip file.
It has the file pythonxx._pth. This file contains list of directory/zip files which embedded python uses to look for modules i.e. to setup sys.path .
For example I have extracted 3.6 embedded version into E:\dev folder.

```
PS C:\Users\user2> get-content E:\dev\python-3.6.5-embed-amd64\python36._pth
python36.zip
.
# Uncomment to run site.main() automatically
#import site
```

sys.path will reflect the same thing

```
PS C:\Users\user2> python
Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 17:00:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['E:\\dev\\python-3.6.5-embed-amd64\\python36.zip', 'E:\\dev\\python-3.6.5-embed-amd64']
>>>
```

Now all I need to do is create a new directory or zip file in E:\dev\python-3.6.5-embed-amd64, which contains all my modules and add that directory in python36._pth file.
Once all the testing is done, I can zip the folder E:\dev\python-3.6.5-embed-amd64 which can be used to deploy Python with all the required modules ready to import.

Comment: ok, but how can I create a new python36.zip with additional *.pyc files inside?

Comment: Or how can I "compile" py files with the same "setting/parameters" like it was done in the python.zip


For example, the file (from zip)
"base_events.pyc" is 31kb and if I precompile it myself (same py file from python installer) the file is 38kb (name is "base_events.cpython-36.pyc" and has much more commentes inside + a full path string inside.

Comment: pythonxx.zip is not supposed to be altered, as it contains built-in standard library. Instead you need to create new one with different name. It is not necessary to compile or zip those files. You can just put all the modules there and as long as all dependencies are there Python won't complain. But if you indeed want to compile you can use py_compile or compileall modules. Compiling entire pip package can be tricky as it contains multiple .py files. For zip you can use 7z or winzip.

Comment: I already have a working portable python package with additional packages. My goal is to make the package smaller AND to reduce the amount of small files. 

So I just create an additional zip file with some py files from Lib and reference it via the _pth file, correct? I will test it right now... :-)

Comment: It seems that not all modules are zip compatible. I use also Jupyter/IPython Notebook and jupyter can find some modules and some not. For example, Jupyter works with "zmq" only if I leave it in the Lib folder.